# How can get value in phonegap which is returned by php class?

Tags: php, android, cordova

I am designing a project in  phonegap with android. i want to show the name using alert message in phonegap which is returned by my php class.
This is my php class:

```
<?php

final class DataStrip
{
        public function DataStrip()
        {
                return "kuntal";  
        }


}
?>
```

Now in my phonegap program i want to display this "kuntal" by using alert. please help me what will be code to do this functionality in phonegap. please check my php class also.

Comment: your PHP should return JSon  to your javascript  you then show an alert from javascript of the data within your Json object

Comment: sir minus4, can you give a example related to this functionality please..?

Comment: google     learning  AJAX     and then google PHP output JSON   am sure you will find lots of examples to play with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your php return a JSON object:

```
final class DataStrip
{
        public function DataStrip()
        {
                return json_encode(array("result"=>"kuntal"));  
        }


}
?>
```

Then in your PhoneGap application, use ajax to get the JSON and alert it (example uses jQuery for brevity):

```
$.getJSON('http://www.domain.com/mypage.php', function(data) {
    alert(data.result);
});
```