# Can PhoneGap apps use server pages to load on it?

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, opendatabase

I am trying to do web apps using **PhoneGap** framework for **iOS.** I need to know whether PhoneGap loads page from server or not, I mean , can I use server side scripting language like *php, pyhon,* etc?
And if I used those scripting language, can I use phone native feature like camera?

Also for data storage there may be feature, I heard **opendatabase** can be used for *online / offline database*. Please anyone help me to figure out these things.
Waiting for good answer.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server side scripts cannot be loaded from within the app, however you can certainly call out to PHP, Python, etc running on a server from the app using AJAX, XHR, etc.

I gave an example in the question below:

[How can get value in phonegap which is returned by php class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119419/how-can-get-value-in-phonegap-which-is-returned-by-php-class)